# Weird array indexing syntax

Tags: python, arrays, syntax, char

I have to translate a script to php but I can't seem to understand what this line does.

```
text = re.split(stop_char, (row[0]+". "+row[1][0:NB_CARAC_MSG]).lower())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: -1 In the future include more information like where you got `row` from and what it contains. Maybe give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is some kind of list/array type. `row[1]` is probably a string.

`0:NB_CARAC_MSG` means "substring from 0 upto `NB_CARAC_MSG-1` (including both).

Comment: So if row is something like [abcdef], that would give ?

Comment: It depends on `NB_CARAC_MSG-1`. If the list is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` and `NB_CARAC_MSG-1` is `3` you would get `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: `[a]` mean "get element with index `a`" and `a` must be an integer. `[a:b]` means "get subset of elements between `[a,b)` (upper bound is not included). when `b` is null, you always get an empty result. Try it: `print "ab"[0:0]`